# Regular Expression for URL validation

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have written regex to validate URL which could be either like

```
google.com

www.google.com

http://www.google.com

https://www.google.com
```

I have used

```
Regex urlRx = new Regex(@"^(http|ftp|https|www)://([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

It works for http & https.It is not working for google./com & www.google.com.

Please help me to solve this.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a nice page with the comparison of different regexes for parsing urls: http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex The best one is: _^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{

Comment: I used this one (without ftp) |^http(s)?://[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$|i

Comment: does it work for www.google.com?

Comment: Be warned, for simple cases, this is simple, for complicated cases (e.g. with a query string or special characters in the url), it's not simple...

Answer (score 61, accepted):

no need for a regex IMHO - try

```
Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(YourURLString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx)

Comment: @PrateekSaluja I am not sure that I understand - `YourURLString` is just normal string... or do have a normal text with some links somewhere in the middle of it ?

Comment: Please test this message.  "Hello how are you? www.google.com"

Comment: @PrateekSaluja ok, that means you don't want to validate URL but you want to find URLs in a arbitrary text... my suggestion won't find the URL... no idea on how to solve that, sorry...

Comment: No problem,Thanks for you time & Your tried that's really helpful even I learned new thing.I am going to give you up vote.Thanks

Comment: **Be careful** using this as the only way to validate a URL, as it allows for URIs such as `javascript:alert('Invitation to hack me');`

Comment: @Yahia - Your answer allows for non-web URLs (eg file paths) and I think the OP is looking to ensure the URLs are valid http/http URLs.

Comment: This doesn't work if you need client side validation.  Granted, this isn't what the OP asked... just making a comment.

Comment: @JosephWoodward - That is absolutely correct. Solution to that is to use `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(Request.Url.ToString(), UriKind.Absolute)` instead. Since UriKind is absolute, it will catch such errors and then when we catch it, we can display an error page, log it or whatever error handling we need to do!

Answer (score 6):

Put the protocol section in an optional group i.e., `()?`:

```
^((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$
```

Comment: `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?$");`

Answer (score 3):

I got this code from jquery.validation (i made some edits)

bool isValid = (Regex.IsMatch(value, @"(((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))).?)(:\d*)?)(/((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)+(/(([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|.|*|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'()*+,;=]|:|@)|/|\?)*)?$"));

I was searching for almost a whole day and this is the best I found.. These are just the few valid samples:

1. example.com
2. example.com.ph
3. www.example.com
4. http://example.com
5. https://example.com
6. http://www.example.com
7. ftp://example.com
8. example.com/doc
9. www.example.com/doc
10. http://example.com/doc
11. http://example.com/questions/12576252/convert-javascript-regex-to-c-sharp-regex-for-email-validation
12. http://www.example.com/wpstyle/?p=364
13. [http://userid:password@example.com:8080](http://userid%3apassword@example.com:8080)
14. https://www.example.com/foo/?bar=baz&inga=42&quux
15. LDAP://ad1.cc.uq.edu.ph

Comment: I tried this one but it returned a false positive for a phone number like this:  `(937) 555-1212`

Answer (score 0):

```
^(http|http(s)?://)?([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+[.com|.in|.org]+(\[\?%&=]*)?
```