# How to Use A MaskType to validate http:\\ links and to validate end of that link with .xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wpf, xmlhttprequest

I know that this question may be a copy or duplicate or similar to validation of URL's. But there is little difference that: I want to  perform validation of link that starts with `http:\\`---- and ends with `.xml`. I used this below code lines by following this link:[Regular Expression for URL validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289007/regular-expression-for-url-validation)

```
  string myString = textBox3.Text;
        Uri myUri;
        if (Uri.TryCreate(myString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out myUri))
        {
            textbox1.Text = myUri.ToString();

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(myUri.ToString());

        }
        else
        {
            textbox2.Text = "NOT VALID";
        }
    }
```

But that pass value by extracting only string after `http:\\`
Can anyone answer my question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is you want to validate some text starts with `http:\\` (presumably `https:\\` ends with `.xml` and is a valid Uri?

Try this static method which does as you like, using `Regex` and `Uri.TryCreate` such as.

```
/// <summary>
/// the regex to match. Uses the Ingore case flag, compiled and single line
/// </summary>
readonly static Regex xmlUriRegex = new Regex("^http(s?)://(.*).xml$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Singleline);

/// <summary>
/// Checks if the string input is a valid XML uri that starts with an http protocol, ends with .xml and is a valid URI
/// </summary>
/// <param name="xmlUri">the uri</param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool IsValidXMLUri(string xmlUri)
{
    Uri u = null;
    return Uri.TryCreate(xmlUri, UriKind.Absolute, out u) && xmlUriRegex.IsMatch(xmlUri);
}
```

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Regex Uprdate.

The regex `^http(s?)://(.*).xml` ensures that the protocol must be `http://` or `https://` and must contain `.xml` in the string. Now I have changed the regex to force the `.xml` file extension to be at the end of the string to: `^http(s?)://(.*).xml$`